# Como hacer que cuando se ejecute un proyecto vaya directo al login?

Tags: php

Saludos! Me pueden **ayudar**

Saben como hacer cuando ejecutan un archivo de su proyecto `PHP` vaya directo al **Login** y no exactamente el archivo que ejecutaste.
Que obligatoriamente cuando se ejecute un archivo, tenga que hacer **Login** para por ver en si el sistema..

Comment: Hola Dev. Den, recomiendo que leas [como elaborar una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y nos comentes que has intentado o como piensas que puede funcionar. Hay mucha información al respecto afuera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilice la funcion header de php http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php
o haga un archivo htaccess y le define el archivo raiz